# How do I run npm commands on Azure App console?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting the following error when I try to run any npm command (like `npm i`) on an Azure app console. It's a Windows instance with Node v10.19.0 and Npm v6.13.4

[image]

Formatted:

```
function(t) {
    if (void 0 === t && (t = "legacy"), this._body instanceof b) return this._body.toString();
    if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) switch (t) {
        case "legacy":
            return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(this._body));
        case "iso-8859":
            return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(this._body));
        default:
            throw new Error("Invalid value for encodingHint: " + t)
    }
    return null == this._body ? "" : "object" == typeof this._body ? JSON.stringify(this._body, null, 2) : this._body.toString()
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the purpose of running `npm i` under the path `D:\home\data\tmp`. But I have solved this problem, first you need to execute in your path:

> 1. npm init
> 2. npm i (install)

In this way, you can execute related commands under your specified path.

The reason you encounter this problem is that the `npm i` command requires a `package.json` file, which requires many parameters, and `npm init` is needed to prompt you to create it.

[image]

**Points for attention of Node in Azure Web App**

1. In the node command, the `-g` command installed globally cannot take effect, and the azure environment cannot be changed.
2. If you encounter a situation where `npm i XXX` cannot be installed, it is recommended to use `Linux` to try. If it still fails, it is recommended to use `docker` or `vm`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying it but I'm already in an initialized folder with package.json and all. In the screenshot I'm in tmp because of all the attempts with different repos, node versions, etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Manuel What do you want to achieve? Or you can change the environment, I did not find that you can create Windows instance with Node v10.19.0 and Npm v6.13.4.

Comment: I'm trying to create a function/service that clones a repo, runs some npm scripts, and return a report. I can get node by creating a Node.js runtime stack or setting the app setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION.